# get value of json returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im doing a ajax call to retrieve data. the data is like this:

```
[{"id":"16","location_name":"agga"}]
```

this is because the php returns: echo `json_encode($getLoc);`

now in the javascript i need to change a input value to the json given ID and show the location name as a string in a div. How can i do this ?

what i tried:

data.id undefined
data[0].id ..undefined
data shows `[{"id":"16","location_name":"agga"}]`

then i tought maybe i need to loop so I did a jquery each... but that also returned nothing..

so now I came here,, what im I doing wrong?

code:

```
 $('#deliveryzip').on('change', function(){

    //Get zip first 4 chars
    var zip = $('#deliveryzip').val().substring(0,4);

        //Check if zip is integer
        if (isNaN(zip)) {
            //alert("zip klopt niet");
            return false;
        }

    //Get locationID from zipcode
    $.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{"zip":zip,"action":"getLocInfo"},function(data){

        $("#locInfo2").html(data); //shows the json returned object
        var show = true;
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Do it like data.first["location_name"]

Comment: alert(data.first["id"]); .. shows error on line 99 wich is this

Comment: @rZaaaa you can see my answer and demo. You need to use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) returns a JSON *string* therefore you need to parse the JSON first into an object and then access the data i.e.

```
//Get locationID from zipcode
$.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{"zip":zip,"action":"getLocInfo"},function(data){
    var location = JSON.parse(data)[0]; // take first item as you appear to receive an array with 1 item
    $('#' + location.id).val(location.location_name); 
    var show = true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.location_name); shows undefined

Comment: @rZaaaa yeah that was a typo, I was in the middle of editing my answer. See my new update.

Comment: Thank you verry much... works now... so the problem was that i was getting 1 result ?

Comment: @rZaaaa no the problem was you were trying to treat the `data` parameter as a JSON object when it was really just a JSON `string` - a `string` doesn't have any properties that's why you were getting `undefined` when attempting to call `data.id` etc. Your JSON data is in the format of an array so when parsed you need to take the first item (assuming it always comes down in one item).

Comment: I see... i tought the php would return the object. Thanks

Comment: @rZaaaa you can return an object from PHP, just don't call `json_encode` on it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Quick example;

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value=""/>
<input type="button" name="update" id="update" value="Update"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#update").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").val(json[0].id);
})
var a = '[{"id":"16","location_name":"agga"}]';
var json = JSON.parse(a);
```

Here you can see demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/y8TwH/**

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
        var json = [{ "id": "16", "location_name": "agga"}];
        alert(json[0]["id"]);
        alert(json[0]["location_name"]);
        $("#locInfo2").html(json[0]["location_name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

is data variable coming from the response a string in json format?
if so then do:

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj[0].id);
```